# ssis replace null with empty string

Tags: ssis, script-component

I am using conditional split on SSIS and I am getting errors as some of the rows contain NULL values. I know this can be changed by using the Derived Column and the REPLACENULL function. However, my table has about 200 columns and this would be very tedious to carry out.

I was wondering if there is anything I can do using Script Component which would loop through all the rows and change any NULLS to an empty string?

Comment: Can you not do this at the Extract or Load stage? What's the data source? db table, flat file, web service?

Comment: The data source is a SQL table. I have managed to do it like this `SELECT ,ISNULL([Col1], '') AS [Col1] FROM [DBO].[MyTable]`. I just wanted to know if there was a better way to do it? @Mazhar

Answer (score 0):

If you can not do the data conversion in your source's select You can do that in on `Script Component` in your `DataFlow.

Before passing your data flow to your `conditional split` you can add a `Script Component` as below image :

[image]

Then in your script component you need to have below code :

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;

[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{

    public override void ProcessInput(int InputID, Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.PipelineBuffer Buffer)
    {
        while (Buffer.NextRow())
        {
            var cols = Buffer.ColumnCount;
            //loop through each column
            for (var i = 0; i < cols; i++)
            {
                //get datatype of the column
                var type = Buffer.GetColumnInfo(i).DataType;
                //only operate on columns of type DT_STR or DT_WSTR
                if (type == DataType.DT_STR || type == DataType.DT_WSTR)
                {
                    //grab the data from the column and trim it
                    var colData = Buffer[i].ToString().Trim();
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(colData))
                    {
                        //if the trimmed data is blank or null, set the output to null
                        Buffer.SetNull(i);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //if the column has data, set the output to the trimmed version
                        Buffer.SetString(i, colData);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


}
```

But as i told and it is mentioned in comment the best way if it is possible is to do that in select when you want to read data from your source.

```
Select 
    ISNULL(A.Field1,'') AS Field1,
    ISNULL(A.Field2,'') AS Field2,
    ....
FROM A
```